# Creating a new role

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I create a new role in my database with my first name which is Denise, and add read only access on the HR user's EMPLOYEES table to this role.

Comment: What DBMS are you working with (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle)? It differes just a bit depending on which DBMS you are referring to.
Are you looking for T-SQL code or do it through a GUI or management tools?

Comment: Wouldn't the t-sql tag indicate the DBMS?

Comment: Well the OP tagged it with clustered-index, which has really nothing to do with the question. I would assume SQL Server is the DBMS but other DBMS questions show up on this site so I just put t-sql for now.

Answer (score 1):

Using Adventureworks database as a reference, following shows sudo code

```
USE [AdventureWorks] 
GO  
CREATE ROLE [Denise] 
GO 
USE [AdventureWorks]  
GO  
GRANT SELECT ON [HumanResources].[Employee] TO [Denise]
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation on MSDN for [Create Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187936.aspx) and [Grant select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx)

```
create role denise identified by appropriateVariable;

grant select on HR.employees to denise;
```

Comment: I'm torn here. I want to welcome another dba to the fold, but this answer is ... less than helpful. I've rewritten it a bit to show you no hard feelings. Welcome to the site, but can we try and put a tad more effort into the posts? :)

Comment: This syntax isn't SQL Server...